# parsing xml data from php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

So I haven't any experience on xml reading with php, I've been doing some research,read some tutorials but there's one thing I'd like to make sure of.
Now I have this xml code below (file.xml):

```
  <location code="TB0023">
    <temp unit="F">15.8</temp>
    <US>Intermittent clouds</US>
  </location>

  <location code="YG0023">
    <temp unit="F">23</temp>
    <US>Mostly Clear</US>
  </location>
```

So the way I access for example temp on location code="TB0023" is this:

```
$open = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
echo $open ->location[0]->temp;
```

Now I've unsuccessfully trying to make it a bit more readable by doing something like this(like associative arrays somehow):

```
$open = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
echo $open ->location[code="TB0023"]->temp;
```

So is there any way to use that identifier TB0023 to retreive data from that specific location, without using indexes 0 1 2 3...

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use xpath; the syntax is almost exactly like you wrote it.

Comment: Thanks. Any possibility to make it work the way I have it actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) framework contains a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class.

Please use [SimpleXMLElement's](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) `path()` method with [Xpath expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

This code from the php.net site

```
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <b>
  <c>text</c>
  <c>stuff</c>
 </b>
 <d>
  <c>code</c>
 </d>
</a>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

/* Search for <a><b><c> */
$result = $xml->xpath('/a/b/c');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '/a/b/c: ',$node,"\n";
}

/* Relative paths also work... */
$result = $xml->xpath('b/c');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'b/c: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

will print this:

```
/a/b/c: text
/a/b/c: stuff
b/c: text
b/c: stuff
```

[XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) is the standard technique to locate elements within XML.

In your case, you'd use an **xpath query** like this:

```
/location[@code="TB0023"]/temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use xpath to query the value in the XML.

`$result = $open->xpath("//location[@code='TB0023']")`

You can find more in the PHP documents [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)